# Building file name from cell arrays with variables

Tags: matlab, variables, printf, cell-array

I want to build a file name from cell arrays. I wanted to use `sprintf` function, but it doesn't work for cell inputs (it works well for example for string arrays).

Example:

```
foldername = sprintf('''\\STH\\Sth %s\\ABC %s;'',firstvariable,secondvariable);
```

Output:

```
Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

Where variables are cell arrays, like that:

```
firstvariable = {'A','B','C'};
secondvariable = {'D','E','F'};
```

I also tried to use `fullfile` function, but it doesn't take any variables. The output from this one look like that: `\STH\Sth %s\ABC %s`. What more, I also tried to use `strcat` function, but the result is pretty the same.

Do you have any other ideas how it can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: So you in this example you want to create a vector of thre filename paths?
(
\A\D\ABC,
\B\E\ABC,
\C\F\ABC )

Comment: The output should for example look like that '\STH\Sth A\ABC D'. I will be doing it in for-loop, so for now I only need to find solution how to save a vector for name with different variables from cell arrays. Sprintf doesn't work on cell arrays; and fullfile and strcat functions are not working with variables. My questions is: what kind of function can do that?

Comment: If you have a `for` loop anyway: get the two desired variables out of their cells in a temporary variable of type `char` and repeat on every iteration.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. I will try to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
for ii = 1:length(firstvariable)
    foldername{ii} = sprintf('''\\STH\\Sth %s\\ABC %s;''',firstvariable{ii},secondvariable{ii});
end
```

The output is:

```
foldername =    {''\STH\Sth A\ABC D;''}    {''\STH\Sth B\ABC E;''}    {''\STH\Sth C\ABC F;''}
```

To use any of the folder names just do the following:

```
foldername{index} % Gives back a string
foldername(index) % Gives back a cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the two cell arrays to [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to loop over them at the same time:

```
firstvariable = {'A','B','C'};
secondvariable = {'D','E','F'};
foldername = cellfun(@(x,y) ['\STH\Sth ' x '\ABC ' y], firstvariable, secondvariable, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This gives

```
foldername =
  1×3 cell array
    '\STH\Sth A\ABC D'    '\STH\Sth B\ABC E'    '\STH\Sth C\ABC F'
```